# Error in jest testing regarding 'react-aad-msal' package

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I'm using react-aad-msal package in a component called Authorizer and when I'm running test I'm getting the following error:

> SyntaxError: 
>   Unexpected token
>
> > import {AzureAD, MsalAuthProviderFactory } from 'react-aad-msal';

the test is very basic and removing the import makes the test green.

```
describe('<Auzthorizer />', () => {
it('should load authorizer without crashing', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Auzthorizer />);
});
```

});

the code for using the "react-aad-msal" package is:

```
   <AzureAD
            provider={new MsalAuthProviderFactory({
                clientID: clientId,
                scopes: ['openid'],
                authority: b2cHost,
                type: "Redirect",
                persistLoginPastSession: true
            })}
            unauthenticatedFunction={this.loginCallback}
            authenticatedFunction={this.logoutCallback}
            userInfoCallback={this.printUserInfo} />
```

Although the tests is failing even when I'm removing the code from the component and there is just the import for the "react-aad-msal"

---

I have created a dummy component just for test with the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AzureAD, MsalAuthProviderFactory } from 'react-aad-msal';


class Test extends Component {

    render() {
        <div></div>
    }
}

export default Test
```

and a test file with the code:

```
import {shallow} from "enzyme";
import test from "./test";
import React from "react";


describe('<test />', () => {
    it('should load authorizer without crashing', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<test />);
    });
});
```

and this is test is still failing.

Comment: Please create a full Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can understand your problem better.

Comment: I can't provide any more code, I provided the code that failing me.

Comment: Providing part of an error isn't the code that's failing you. If we can't see how your tests are written or more than "Unexpected token" then how can we help? Those errors usually show a lot more detail than that. It could be that your issue is on a different line

Answer (score -1):

With the code you have above I don't understand how it is even running a test. You are shallow mounting a component but you're saving it to a variable `wrapper` without performing any tests against it. This is an example of how to run a simple test.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Test from './test';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('shallow mounts', () => {
    shallow(<Test />);
  });
});
```

What I was referring to about using the import on the test file is if your component that you're trying to mount requires a particular prop or needs to be wrapped by a particular component then you need to import them on the test file as well.

**Example of needing third party 'moment'**

In this sample there is a function inside of `<Test />` which uses `moment`

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Test from './test';
import moment from 'moment';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('mounts without crashing', () => {
    mount(<Test />);
  });
});
```

**Example of wrapping component needed 'APIProvider'**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Test from './test';
import { APIProvider } from './api-context';

describe('Test', () => {
  it('mounts with API Context', () => {
    mount(
      <APIProvider>
          <Test />
      </APIProvider>
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean? the test is initializing the component with this import for "react-aad-msal" and than it fails...

Comment: So `import {AzureAD, MsalAuthProviderFactory } from 'react-aad-msal';` is inside of your `Auzthorizer` component, not your test file? This is what I meant by needing to be more clear about your problem and providing code samples. How are you using the imports in your component?

Comment: Try adding the same import to your test file, make sure that you are passing the necessary props to your `Auzthorizer` component.

Comment: I didn't understand the import in the test thing but it didn't work.

Comment: also edited the question again with a very simple example.

Comment: I've updated my answer, It's really hard to troubleshoot with having much visibility. Hopefully my latest update helps to clear things up.

Comment: I changed the test to looks like yours and I still got the same error, also tried to add the import inside the test without success, honestly I don't understand why the variable wrapper is disturbing you, the meaning is to continue the test afterward using the wrapper variable.
did you use the 'react-aad-msal' directory before?
if not please stop try to find errors that doesn't exists.

Comment: I haven't used that library in particular before but I have been working with Jest and the error you noted was a very generic error. If you don't want my help then fine, best of luck.